# Using EnsureUser with ADFS

Tags: authentication, spweb, adfs, spuser, claims

I am trying to take some users and author them to list item posts. The `SPWeb.EnsureUser()` method works fine on a server only utilizing `AD`, but not one that is using `ADFS`.

Here is my attempt at checking users against `ADFS`.

```
//<Claim>|<Claim Issuer>|<Value>
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("i:05.t|myIssuer|someone@domain.com");
```

Please keep in mind that `someone@domain.com` exists in `AD`, but has not necessarily logged into SharePoint.

Is this of correct format? Is there somewhere I can pull `<Claim>` and `<Claim Issuer>` so I can ensure I am using the correct providers?

Answer (score 0):

`SPWeb.EnsureUser` evaluates against Active Directory (Windows) and Forms-based Authentication Claim providers. Since you're using a SAML provider (regardless if the user is originating from Active Directory), there is nothing for SharePoint to attempt to resolve against.

In other words, what you're seeing is by design.